# Deliver app for beta testing

Tags: android, android-testing

I am about to deploy my app for beta testing. However, I am confused on the best way to safely deliver to beta tester devices.

I understand emailing apk file is not a logical move.

Having done a bit of research, I found the following.

1. [Deploy Gate](https://deploygate.com)- offers private over-the-air distribution.
2. [Google Play Private Channel for Google Apps](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&hlrm=en&answer=2494992)
   - did not quite hold of it.
3. [Zubhium](https://www.zubhium.com)- new platform. Has anyone tried this before?

Could anyone please walk me through an appropriate method?

Comment: Why do you say that emailing the APK isn't logical? I understand it's far from ideal, in some cases, but it's certainly an efficient means of delivery.

Comment: There is not any built in copy protection to lock an APK to a single device so a tester could redistribute your application without your consent. And there is no crash analytics possible this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing with beta testing is that you *always* run the risk of the apk being leaked. There is literally nothing you can do to prevent this, as anyone with a rooted device can retrieve the apk after installation.

You should instead consider adding features like timed trials to the apk, and have it stop working after a certain date, or after a certain value on the server has changed.

Additionally, beta testing is a matter of trust. If you do not trust your beta testers, don't give them an apk.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Could you explain 'timed trials to the apk' a bit more?

Comment: @Renjith Add a check that runs everytime the app starts to see if the date is within the range you want your beta to last. For example, if you want it to stop working after May 1st, then check the date and show an error message if that current date is after May 1st

Comment: one limitation with emailing app is that there is no way for crash analytic. How do you re-create a reported exception or see the logs?

Comment: @Renjith Integrate [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) into your apps

Comment: Thanks! I have it a go.

Answer (score 2):

Starting on May '13 Google Play Developer Console lets you test your app with groups of users through alpha- and beta-testing and staged rollouts feature.  You need to:

1. Select an APK for your alpha or beta test.
2. Select the group of users for each test.
3. Publish your alpha- or beta-test APK.
4. Ask your testers to opt in.

The alpha/beta testers must be part of either a [Google group](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/46601) or a [Google+ community](https://support.google.com/plus/topic/2888488).
the app will only appear in Google Play for testers that opt-in and not to any other users. Another inconvenient is that it may take up to 24 hours after publishing for the test link to become active, but normally it will be less time

Here you can find more information about [Beta-testing and staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213)